# Is having two envoy proxies in the same K8S pod a good practice?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, envoyproxy

My application is deployed in GKE, I'm trying to deploy Istio (1.2.2) and I ran into a problem:
One of the deployments is a pod consisting of two containers - gRPC service and an Envoy proxy.
we use the envoy as a workaround to expose an HTTP2 healthcheck for the Google loadbalancer, since the gRPC service is exposed to the world and healthcheck is mandatory.

When Istio injects it's envoy sidecar to this pod, all hell breaks loose:

1. The requests hit the existing envoy proxy and not the istio-sidecar.
2. Google healthchekcs to the backend servie fail.

the question arises - should I try to make both of the proxies work together or is it better to have only the Istio sidecar in this pod?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to make both of the proxies to work since that Istio version is unable to distinguish between Health Checks and actual traffic.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can find more information on the official [Istio release notes](https://github.com/istio/istio/compare/1.2.1...1.2.2).